# C# move object to another with speed in 3D Dimension

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have a C# application which I use as a dedicated TCP server to be used by my Unity Client.

In unity you move your object towards another with the following code:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Target.transform.position, FlyingSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

I have the coordinates of both objects in my dedicated server app. Here is how I calculate distance between my objects in my server app:

```
public static float CalculateDistance(Position position1, Position position2){
    float deltaX = position1.x - position2.x;
    float deltaY = position1.y - position2.y;
    float deltaZ = position1.z - position2.z;

    float distance = (float)Math.Sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY + deltaZ * deltaZ);
    Console.WriteLine("Distance is: " + distance);
    return distance;
}
```

My question is:
How can i create similar function to `Vectror3.MoveTowards` in my server app ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: In your server app, do you have a timer that is synced with the client? if yes then you can use this timer and a linear movement algorithm to simulate the movement. you dont have sync time you can still simulate the movement with the same algorithm but eventually they will get out of sync (client will be in position A and server will thing player is in position B, where A != B)

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with the code

```
  Vector3 MoveTowards(Vector3 current, Vector3 to, float step){
       if(current != to)
           return Normalize(to - current) * step;
    }
```

This uses normalization, if you do not have this defined. You can create a function:

```
Vector3 Normalize(Vector3 normalize){
     return normalize / (normalize.x + normalize.y + normalize.x)
}
```

This also assumes that you have a way to define a Vector3. You may also have to define a threshold where it forces both positions to equal - without this you may get an effect where the current position travels back and forth through the destination.